# ApplicationPool Class Object properties not available in WMI

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic, iis-8, application-pool

I am managing my IIS Application Pools using a local VBScript on the machine, or through an ASP page running under a highly-privileged identity.

The Microsoft documentation lists all the available properties and methods for an **ApplicationPool Class** Object on this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms690608.

Altough I am able to use the **.Recycle**, **.Start** and **.Stop** methods, and the **.Name** property, all the other methods and properties are not available for the Application Pool, like *.GetState*, *.AutoStart*, *.ManagedPipelineMode*...

Is the documentation broken ?

```
'For VBSCRIPT
Set o_Wbem_Locator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set o_Wbem_Service = o_Wbem_Locator.ConnectServer("MyServerName", "root/MicrosoftIISv2")
Set o_Wbem_AppPoolsCollection = o_Wbem_Service.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM IISApplicationPool")
For Each o_Wbem_AppPoolInstance In o_Wbem_AppPoolsCollection
    'Work
    o_Wbem_AppPoolInstance.Recycle

    'Work
    WScript.Echo o_Wbem_AppPoolInstance.Name

    'DOES NOT Work
    WScript.Echo o_Wbem_AppPoolInstance.GetState

    'DOES NOT Work
    WScript.Echo o_Wbem_AppPoolInstance.ManagedPipelineMode
Next
```

Comment: When you say *"Not available"* can you be a bit more descriptive, like for example *"other methods and properties are not available, when calling them VBScript returns the error ... (insert actual error here)"*. Just saying that doesn't help diagnose the problem, we can guess but we wouldn't have to if you describe what actually happens when you try to call these methods or reference these properties.

Comment: Again, like your previous issue it's likely permissions not the *"documentation broken"*. Try running your script locally first, rather then specifying a remote computer, then once it works locally move on to getting it working remotely.

Comment: The documentation is quite clear. You need to connect `WebAdministration` namespace not `MicrosoftIISv2` and query from `ApplicationPool` not `IISApplicationPool`. The provider you're trying to make it work with IIS 7.0 is old and is for IIS 6.0. There's a working example code, please try to run it first.

Comment: Sorry @Lankymart, I should have been more precise ! The returned error from VBScript as from ASP is **"Object doesnt support this property or method: o_Wbem_AppPoolInstance.GetState"**. Also, I am running this script locally, under the fully-privileged *"Administrator"* account - I am not trying to connect to a remote computer.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin : You ae absolutely RIGHT ! I have spent hours between the Microsoft Documentation on micrisift.com, on iis.net, and on StackOverflow, guessing that some syntax may have changed between IIS 6 and IIS 7, and trying to use *"The Good One"*..., and I have failed to ! Your comment totally solve my problem, so I will post an Answer now. I thank you very much for your time and concise explanations !

Comment: @AlexLaforge look at [Kul-Tigin's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48628772/applicationpool-class-object-properties-not-available-in-wmi?noredirect=1#comment84262202_48628772), they have already pointed you in the right direction. The method you are using is for an older version of IIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HERE IS THE SOLUTION :)**

As stated by ***@Kul-Tigin*** in the comments, I was connecting to the wrong Namespace, and querying the wrong Object Class.

### **NAMESPACE**

- *"root/MicrosoftIISv2"* is suitable for **IIS 6**
- *"root/WebAdministration"* is suitable for **IIS 7 [and Higher]**

### **OBJECT CLASS TO QUERY**

- *"SELECT * FROM IISApplicationPool"* is suitable for **IIS 6**
- *"SELECT * FROM ApplicationPool"* is suitable for **IIS 7 [and Higher]**

So the correct working code to manage IIS 7+ Application Pools using WMI from Vbscript or ASP is the following one :

```
'For VBSCRIPT
Set o_Wbem_Locator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")

'Suitable for IIS 6
'Set o_Wbem_Service = o_Wbem_Locator.ConnectServer("MyServerName", "root/MicrosoftIISv2")

'Suitable for IIS 7+
Set o_Wbem_Service = o_Wbem_Locator.ConnectServer("MyServerName", "root/WebAdministration")

'Suitable for IIS 6
'Set o_Wbem_AppPoolsCollection = o_Wbem_Service.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM IISApplicationPool")

'Suitable for IIS 7+
Set o_Wbem_AppPoolsCollection = o_Wbem_Service.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM ApplicationPool")


For Each o_Wbem_AppPoolInstance In o_Wbem_AppPoolsCollection
    'Works in IIS 6 and in IIS 7+
    o_Wbem_AppPoolInstance.Recycle    

    'Works in IIS 6 and in IIS 7+
    WScript.Echo o_Wbem_AppPoolInstance.Name    

    'DOES NOT Work in IIS 6
    'Works in IIS 7+
    WScript.Echo o_Wbem_AppPoolInstance.GetState    

    'DOES NOT Work in IIS 6
    'Works in IIS 7+
    WScript.Echo o_Wbem_AppPoolInstance.ManagedPipelineMode
Next
```

I wish to kindly thank ***@Kul-Tigin*** for pointing this fundamental difference in the required syntax, and many thanks to all the other commentators that contributed to make me able to polish my IIS Application Pool management. I am now able to automate some actions to ensure that my Application Pools are up, well, and running ;)